# Remove from string onwards from string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i understand this type of question has been asked many times, but i can't seem to get it right. i do have a path C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Tutorial Walkthrough\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug. Any idea how i can remove the substring \bin onwards? currently i have have got the following code

```
string DirDebug = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\\");
        int i = DirDebug.IndexOf("\bin");
        DirDebug = DirDebug.Remove(i);
        MessageBox.Show(DirDebug)
```

but it is not showing what i want. any idea how i can achieve C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Tutorial Walkthrough\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1? any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: What _does_ this show?

Comment: You need to escape `\bin` to `\\bin`.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect example of where you can provide: a) a short but *complete* program, e.g. a console app; b) expected output; c) actual output. Ideally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`DirectoryInfo` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
string path= @"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Tutorial Walkthrough\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug";
string rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(path).Parent.Parent.FullName;
```

The result is:

```
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Tutorial Walkthrough\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1
```

As an aside, if you want to get that path for your current application you can use [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName;
```

For the sake of completeness, if i  you want a general string approach you could use this:

```
string[] token = path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
var allButTwoLast = token.Take(token.Length - 2);
string result = string.Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), allButTwoLast);
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, sorry for the confusion. i do have a path C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Tutorial Walkthrough\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug. however i want to remove the substring from \bin onwards, and Mr Tim Schmelter just solved my problem. Thank you!

> string DirDebug = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\");
>   string newpath = new DirectoryInfo(DirDebug).Parent.Parent.FullName;
>               MessageBox.Show(newpath);

the above is the solution

Comment: If he did, upvote his post and/or accept as answer :).